# Is using >= and <= to specify enum values good code practice?

Tags: enums, language-agnostic, enumeration

I am working on a project with about 8 other people, and would like to know the best code practice here, given that other people will be working on this code for years to come.

Say I have an enum with 10 values:

```
typedef enum {
    Tag1 = 1,
    Tag2,
    Tag3,
    Tag4,
    Tag5,
    Tag6,
    Tag7,
    Tag8,
    Tag9,
    Tag10
} Tag;
```

If I wanted to check if a tag is equal to Tag6, Tag7, Tag8, Tag9, or Tag10, is it good practice to using a comparison like:

```
if(myTag >= Tag6 && myTag <= Tag10) {
    //Do something
}
```

?

Or is it best to use an OR and check for each tag?

Using >= and <= looks nicer and is less clunky, but if down the line, someone were to insert a new Tag between Tag7 and Tag8, it would mess up all the logic.

Can I expect that someone wouldn't add a new Tag between other Tags?

Comment: have you considered using bit masks ?

Comment: I have not heard of this concept, I will look in to it thank you!

Comment: What's the significance of a tag being in Tag6, Tag7, Tag8, Tag9, or Tag10?  If these are something like priority levels, then someone adding a tag between 7 and 8 should probably be included in the logic of your current code. If they are disparate and incomparable meanings, then the additional tag should not be in your current code (or should be considered when that tag is added). It depends on what your if condition means. Also, if the semantics of the enum are clearly signified, then future developers hopefully will do the right thing when adding new tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I expect that someone wouldn't add a new Tag between other Tags?

I wouldn't bet on it. Unless the enum's ordinal/underlying values have some inherent meaning or order I would avoid using them to much.

I would only use range checks if I actually *want* somebody to be able to insert additional enums without adapting all checks. This is probably a rather rare case though. [Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905/keith) gives a good examples with the Priority enum, another example I can think of are log levels.

The exact syntax depends on the language of course but I would usually consider something like this as most readable:

```
if(myTag in [Tag6, Tag7, Tag8]) {
    // ... 
}
```

Or even better use some describing variable names which make it obvious what the other tags are:

```
topTags = [Tag6, Tag7, Tag8]

if(myTag in topTags) {
    // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but *only* for enums that express a *scale* of values, for instance:

```
enum Priority {
    None = 0,
    Low,
    Medium,
    High,
    Critical
}
```

Then this code makes sense and is readable:

```
if(message.Priority >= Priority.Medium) {
     // Notify user
}
```

If the enum doesn't express a scale like this then avoid using `<` or `>` as they can be rather confusing. Use bit flags instead.

Flags enums use binary values so that values can be combined:

```
enum UserAudiences {
    // Basic values:  dec // binary
    None            = 0,  // 0000
    Client          = 1,  // 0001
    Employee        = 2,  // 0010
    Contractor      = 4,  // 0100
    Key             = 8,  // 1000

    // Combined:      dec // binary
    KeyClient       = 9,  // 1001 : Key + Client          
    BoardMember     = 10, // 1010 : Key + Employee        
    CounterParty    = 5,  // 0101 : Client + Contractor
    BusinessPartner = 13  // 1101 : Key + Client + Contractor
}
```

Then, when checking for a combined enum value we look at the binary number and whether the appropriate bit is set. For instance if we want to check for `UserAudiences.Employee` we can just look for the bit that represents 2, if it is set then we have one of the enum values that includes it:

```
if((message.Audience & UserAudiences.Employee) != 0) {
    // Post on intranet
} else {
    // Send externally
}
```

There's no way to set that bit through any combination of `Key`, `Client` or `Contractor` enums, it can only be set if `Employee` is one of the 'source' enums.

Most languages have helpers for this (or you can write your own):

```
if(message.Audience.HasFlag(UserAudiences.Employee)) { ...
```

The maths could work in any base - you could use 1, 10, 100, etc in decimal. However, you'd need much bigger numbers much sooner.

Finally, there's a convention to use singular names for regular enums, and plural names for flagged enums, hinting to the programmer whether to use equality or bitwise checks.